# if statements with class value not working

Tags: jquery, class, if-statement

can someone explain to me why this isn't working. logically it makes sense, but is there a better way to do it?

```
$('#n2').click(function() {
    if ($('#b0').attr('class') == 'box position0') {
        movedown2
    }
})​
```

Comment: Without the accompanying HTML, we can't tell if this is right or not.

Comment: well it's supposed to run function movedown2 when #n2 is clicked, but only if #b0 has class equal to 'box position0'

Comment: You probably want to use http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Comment: Which part fails? The click the class check? Have you thrown in window.alert() or console.log() to see which part is failing? You might also look into using the hasClass function rather than attr

Comment: ok so here's my code http://jsfiddle.net/peyTr/ I need it to update the class when I switch it, so that it only runs that function when it's a specific class. hasClass doesn't work for that either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like below,

```
$('#b0').is('.box.position0'))
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qrw7x/)

or

```
$('#b0')[0].className == 'box position0'
```

Also you were missing function call `()`.

```
$('#n2').click( function(){ 
   if( $('#b0').is('.box.position0') ) {
     movedown2(); //Note the () added which was missing in your orig code
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from this fiddle, the jQuery you have should get into your if statement just fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/6TbT5/

The fact that you have `movedown2` floating around in there may be your problem.  You will have to post your HTML for me to be sure.